# select brushed selection on load with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, parallel-coordinates

I'm implementing the [parallel coordinates](http://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/1341281) d3.js visualization, and I was wondering if there is a way of pre-selecting a brushed selection on page load (or on button click).

I know I need to do some of the following, but it is not clear to me what is the relevant part:

```
  .call(d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("dragstart", function(d) {
      dragging[d] = this.__origin__ = x(d);
      background.attr("visibility", "hidden");
    })
    .on("drag", function(d) {
      dragging[d] = Math.min(w, Math.max(0, this.__origin__ += d3.event.dx));
      foreground.attr("d", path);
      dimensions.sort(function(a, b) { return position(a) - position(b); });
      x.domain(dimensions);
      g.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + position(d) + ")"; })
    })
    .on("dragend", function(d) {
      delete this.__origin__;
      delete dragging[d];
      transition(d3.select(this)).attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d) + ")");
      transition(foreground)
          .attr("d", path);
      background
          .attr("d", path)
          .transition()
          .delay(500)
          .duration(0)
          .attr("visibility", null);
    }))
```

Comment: Do you want a brush or drag? Note that you can set the extent of a brush programmatically using `brush.extent()`.

Comment: Refer here [example](http://syntagmatic.github.io/parallel-coordinates)

Comment: which one of the examples, @Gilsha? I looked there but did not find what I needed.